# Filling email template from C# program

Tags: c#, email, templates

I am looking for guides to do such task. I generate subject, body, recipient in C# program and I need to send this info to default email program like Outlook which would then have a new email template filled according to what I sent. Then the user will only need to click send or, if needed, modify something and do what he wants with that email. The problem is that I only manage to find various examples of how to send email but not how to open default program on the computer and fill the data. Any guidance on how to search is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [mailto URI scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto).

```
Process.Start("mailto:someone@example.com?cc=someone_else@example.com&subject=This%20is%20the%20subject&body=This%20is%20the%20body");
```

[image]

Comment: Correct answer but a side note with use of URL scheme as stated above you may not be able to send more then N number of character. So your body should not be that much more. Just a defensive programming approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
Outlook.Application oApp    = new Outlook.Application ();
Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem ( Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem );
oMailItem.To    = address;
oMailItem.body    = body;
// body, bcc etc...
oMailItem.Display ( true );
```

This is using with usage Outlook interops.

Alternate is to System.Process....

```
Process.Start(String.Format("mailto:{0}?subject={1}&cc={2}&bcc={3}&body={4}", address, subject, cc, bcc, body))
```

Above both will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/

This is however just Outlook, using .Net for Office. Unless the program you are trying to send the email with has some kind of API (like Outlook), or you happen to have a program to take control of keyboard and mouse directly (and that would be desperate), I don't see how you can do it. Either way you'll have to customize your program for each external tool; that is the code for Outlook will be different from the code for Thunderbird.